# Python Pandas identifying incorrect data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file delimited by comma and there are 215 columns per row. The files is very huge I am using pandas dataframe pd.read_csv() with chunks to read the data. One of the row in file has 214 columns instead of 215 columns but dataframe reads the data with NaN applied to last column.

Is there a way to identify this row in pandas dataframe as I prefer dataframe instead of csv_reader.

Note: The last column can be null also so filtering the dataframe by last column equal to null will not work

Comment: Please show us what you tried? Also, would be nice to see some sample data.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the read_csv() function treats missing columns and empty columns the same (as empty strings), so you can't distinguish what you want with a single read_csv function call. I think you'd have to preprocess the file somehow to be able to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the nulls row wise and then filter for those where sum is not equal to 0
This will give you rows with nulls.

```
df[df.isnull().sum(axis=1)!=0]
```

Comment: the files can have null values. So isnull will select valid rows as well. How can I handle this.

Comment: in pd.read_csv there is an option `na_filter`, set it to False and try. Details here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html